# Laravel - Scheduling a Large Task

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks

Trying to run a function in Laravel that's quite large and fetches a lot of data from Google Places API and stores parts in my database as new entries in a table. The problem is it auto-discovers new entries for me near my current entries, and that creates more jobs.

When I just access the command via GET it times out eventually. I've tried running it as a scheduled command with Redis but to be frank I can't seem to figure out how it works. I've created a job, I tried to queue it with dispatch, but then it tries to run it immediately right now and it times out eventually again.

How do I run this large task without it pausing my entire server?

Thanks

- Zach

Comment: did u deal with it?

Comment: I ended up using your solution on bottom and creating a new artisan command, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is really simple and you do not need to stop server. It is just CRON job. Use Laravel Schedule.

When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server.

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Class example:

```
namespace App\Console;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
        })->daily();
    }
}
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Nice video about laravel scheduling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp-XZm7INl8

Comment: How can I make it run now? I've looked into the scheduler, and to be frank I'm using it right now and it doesn't run

Comment: step by step simply explained on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mp-XZm7INl8

Comment: yes, you just set scheduler task, you do not need artisan command: $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('recent_users')->delete();
        })->daily();